# Relationship items are also populated regardless of not calling them

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following:

```
class Test
{
    public virtual IList<TestLike> TestLikes { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository method that looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<Test> GetTests()
{
    return this.context.Tests;
}
```

When I call it in my controller:

```
List<Test> tests = this.testRepository.GetTests().ToList();
```

and then look at it in the debugger, it has also populated all of the `TestLikes` that are attached to it as well... I did not have to enumerate the debugger to list them, they are just there.

How do I delay this happening until I actually need them?

Answer (score 2):

> and then look at it in the debugger, it has also populated all of the
>   TestLikes that are attached to it as well... I did not have to
>   enumerate the debugger to list them, they are just there.

Looks like [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy) is enabled. Navigating to the properties inside **the debugger itself** triggers the SQL request. The SQL requests won't be executed if you do not look at the navigation properties inside the debugger.

Comment: Oh, how confusing. Thank you... I'm actually quite glad... phew!